# How to position loading animation inside input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to position my loading animation on the same line, inside my input box, to the right.

I tried :

```
<span>
    <input id="searchbox" placeholder="Enter Catalog # " type="text" />
    <img style="float:right;" id='loading' width="100px" src="http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/shared_images/ajax-loader.gif"/> 
</span>
```

I get :

[image]

I couldn't get it to show inside my input box. :(

Comment: Try setting the image as the background of the input element.

Comment: In my case, it is a loading animation. It doesn't display all the time. It's only display when my application is trying to query data out of my database. I am not sure - if setting it as a background image would be the best way to do. :D

Comment: You could set it as the background of the input with a specific class, so `input.loading { background: url(...) }` and then just toggle that class whenever you want to load stuff.

Comment: @Chad : Your suggestion might be the solution. I hope you don't mind provide more details by answer this question for all of us.

Answer (score 45):

You can also do it as a background image in CSS. Just create a CSS class and apply at the time of loading the data. After Ajax call is completed remove the "loading" CSS class from the text input box.

```
.loading {    
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url("http://loadinggif.com/images/image-selection/3.gif");
    background-size: 25px 25px;
    background-position:right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

You can view it here: http://jsfiddle.net/tejsoft/7pzgtevv/4/

Answer (score 11):

I agree with @Sam in that it could be the background of the element, and all you'd have to toggle would be a class. If you set it up like:

```
input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}
input.loading {
    background: url(http://www.xiconeditor.com/image/icons/loading.gif) no-repeat right center;
}
```

And then you can toggle the class as you're making your ajax call like:

```
$(document).on('blur', 'input', function(e) {
    var $t = $(e.currentTarget);
    $t.addClass('loading');
    $.ajax({
        url: $t.data('ajax'),
        success: function(data) {
            //dostuff
            $t.removeClass('loading');
        }
    });
});
```

That, in my opinion, would be the simplest and most effective way of doing it. If you want to look further, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzv45aq5/)

Comment: @iori yes it does, just applied it on the blur of the input, so when you focus out of it.

Comment: Holy crap! I spent so many hours trying to make a reusable select loader with a wrapper div. I had never even though about using gif as background. SO MUCH EASIER!!! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try fiddling around with absolutely positioning the element.

fiddle

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 112px;
    top: -22px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kmbxawdd/2/

Furthermore, you can set the containing elements position to relative, meaning you can style directly to these dimensions rather than the documents.

Comment: I am not sure if this would be the ideal solution, because, what if the user display it on tablets, or phones ?

Comment: I respect that completely, but `position: absolute;
    left: 112px;
    top: -22px;` will place my loading animation in the absolute position, and I am not sure that this might be the best way to do it.

Comment: Which would still work fine on phones assuming it's in a relative container @lori

Answer (score 1):

My solution: add a class to the input element that defines a background image, then modify its position with ***background-position-x*** and ***background-position-y***

```
.Loading {
    background-image: url("bg.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat ;
    background-position-x: 99% ;
    background-position-y: 50% ;
}
```

you can also use keywoords for postioning

```
background-position-x: right;
background-position-y: center;
```

or combine them

```
background-position: center right;
```

then, you can just add or remove this class to show/hide the animation

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Place the animation after the input field in the HTML
2. Set `position: relative;` on the image

   - Allows you to tweak the position of the element from where it would be by default
3. Use the `top` CSS attribute to shift the animation upward to the point where it is directly on top of the input field.

Comment: I am not sure if this would be the ideal solution, because, what if the user display it on tablets, or phones ?

Comment: I am not the one that did that. I swear.

Comment: @iori The device shouldn't matter.

Comment: I tried `position: relative;
 top: 20%;
 float: right;' I feel like my top property doesn't work, and the loading animation is still displaying outside of the input box. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Try using a negative pixel offset for `top`.

Answer (score 0):

Place both the `input` and the `img` inside a div and make that `div` look like a text box. I am currently on my phone so it might not be perfect but I think you get the point.

http://jsfiddle.net/soz8jq2x/

Answer (score 0):

just include `<img>` element inside `<input>` element.then you can use js to show and hide this image using id attribute.

```
<img class="loading" src="http://loadinggif.com/images/image-selection/3.gif" id="img-loading">

.loading {    
    position: absolute;
    top: 206px;
    right: 30px;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: this wont be responsive!