# MVC 5 jQuery UI Autocomplete textbox, get other item details on value selection

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

**Question:**
In [**jQuery UI Autocomplete**](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) text box ( ASP.NET MVC 5 Razor environment ),
When the user selects a value, the other fields on the form should be filled automatically

Below is AutoComplete implementation. (so far it works)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("GetItemCode")',
        minLength: 1
    });
});
</script>
```

Now, when the user selects an item from autocomplete textbox,
the other fields on the form should get filled.

Tried to implement the [jQuery Autocomplete API docs, on select](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select/)
but to no avail

```
select: function (event, ui) {
         //fill selected customer details on form
         $.ajax({
             cache: false,
             async: false,
             type: "POST",
             url: "@(Url.Action("GetItemDetails", " Home"))",
            data: { "id": ui.item.Id },

            success: function (data) {
                $("#ItemName").val(data.ItemName);
               ...
               ...
```

getting nothing but errors:

1. undefined, // json undefined
2. 500 Internal Server Error // json

As Said, the autocomplete is working, I am looking for the details ( other form controls - textboxes ) to autofill on value selection from autocomplete textbox.

Comment: `$("#ItemName").val(data.ItemName);`

Comment: I am making a question and answer, Answer is ready .. jus few edits,
and thanks .. the item/data.. was jus a typo.. basically there was the need to handle array in json data returned.. wait a while while I answer it completely

Comment: SO is not a blog site. Your question does not even indicate what the problem is. And the code in your answer does not answer a question because there is no question to answer.

Comment: ok I have reworded it, Does it fit SO now ..

Comment: Its still not a question! No where in it do you indicate what is not working, or what the controller method is or what data it returns or what the html is.

Comment: mentioned my errors and other details in much clearer fashion, if that's what's required.

Comment: No, because there is no information in the question to allow it to be answered. Refer [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) for an example - I created it primarily to dupe-hammer numerous other similar questions. There is nothing wrong with creating your own question/answer, but it needs to be a clear problem statement, not just a vehicle for you to write some code in an answer.

Comment: people for whom it is written will automatically reach here and get benefited. the details in the questions are enough for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:**

a working implementation:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css")">   
<script src="@Url.Content("//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js")"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("#ItemCode").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var itemnamecodes = new Array();
            $.ajax({
                async: false, cache: false,
                //type: "POST",
                url: "@(Url.Action("GetItemCode", "Home"))",
                data: { "term": request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
                        itemnamecodes[i] = { label: data[i].Value, Id: data[i].Key };
                    }
                 }
            });
            response(itemnamecodes);
        },
         select: function (event, ui) {                 
             $.ajax({
                 cache: false, async: false, type: "POST",
                 url: "@(Url.Action("GetItemDetails", "Home"))",
                 data: { "id": ui.item.Id },                    
                success: function (data) {                       
                    var item = data[0];                          
                    $("#ItemName").val(item.ItemName);
                    $("#ItemModel").val(item.ItemModel);                       
                    ... the other details you need 
                    action = data.Action;
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve Item.');
                }
            });
        }
});      
});
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 ...
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ItemCode, ...
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ItemName, ...
  ... other form elements to show details
```

In Controller,

```
  public JsonResult GetItemCode(string term)
  {        
       // var codes = db.w_Items.Where(i => i.ItemCode.StartsWith(term)).ToList();
        var result = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        var namecodes = new List<SelectListItem>();
        namecodes = (from u in db.w_Items select new SelectListItem { Text = u.ItemCode, Value = u.w_ItemId.ToString() }).ToList();

        foreach (var item in namecodes)
        {
            result.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(item.Value.ToString(), item.Text));
        }

        var namecodes1 = result.Where(s => s.Value.ToLower().Contains
                    (term.ToLower())).Select(w => w).ToList();
     return Json(namecodes1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }

  [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
  public JsonResult GetItemDetails(int id)
  {            
        var codeList = db.w_Items.Where(i => i.w_ItemId == id).ToList();

        var viewmodel = codeList.Select(x => new
        {
            Id = x.w_ItemId,
            ItemName = x.ItemName,
            ItemModel = x.ItemModel,               
            ... the other details you need

        });

        return Json(viewmodel);           
   }
```

Two things that were irking:
**(Solutions here)**
the json data is in the form of *array*, so you need to treat it likewise:

```
var item = data[0];
```

and another very irking thing.. solution now:

you need to pass viewmodel with **specific** properties as json result to be handled in View

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it hope it helps.

---

Css

---

```
enter code here.isloading1 {   
background-color: #ffffff;
background-image: url("http://loadinggif.com/images/image-selection/3.gif");
background-size: 16px 16px;
background-position:right center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

---

### thanks  to [TejSoft](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28823545)

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AutoComplete(string prefix)
    {
        var customers = _CustomerRepo.getCustomerDetails(prefix);
        return Json(customers);
    }
```

---

JS

```
$(function () {
$("#Customer_Name").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Controller/AutoComplete/',
            data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {


                    return {
                        //value is the default list value in auto compleate drop down
                        value: item.CustomerName,
                        id: item.CustomerID,
                        CustomerAddress: item.CustomerAddress,
                        CustomerCity: item.CustomerCity,
                        CustomerPostcode: item.CustomerPostcode

                    };

                }));
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    },

    select: function (e, i) {
        //TestCode
        // alert("CustomerName - " + i.item.value + " PostCode - " + i.item.CustomerPostcode + " CustomerCity - " + i.item.CustomerCity + " CustomerAddress - " + i.item.CustomerAddress);

        //set value for hiden field
        $("#pickup_addressline2").val(i.item.CustomerAddress);
        $("#CustomerCity").val(i.item.CustomerCity);
        $("#CustomerID").val(i.item.ID);
        $("#CustomerPostcode").val(i.item.CustomerPostcode);
    },
    minLength: 1,
    /* Show spinner while loading data #2 */
    search: function () {
        $("#Customer_Name").addClass("isloading1");
    },
    response: function () {
        $("#Customer_Name").removeClass("isloading1");
    }


});
});
```